# woocommerce thumbnail replace with original image filter

Tags: woocommerce

My problem in woocommerce :

```
 <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Handmade-e1588339358176-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" />
```

How i want it to be :

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Handmade-e1588339358176.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" />
```

In functions.php i have

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
       return array(
          'width'  =>  150,
          'height' => 150,
          'crop'   => 1,
       );
   });
```

Or anyway to remove the width="" and height="" attributes ... so i make my imgs responsive from css ?

Comment: WordPress will fetch the nearest size picture of the dimension you provide. Instead of using filter you can try getting the image id and then user wp_get_attachment_image and user the size as full size. But that won't add the 150x150 in the width and height properly of the image tag. Else you can add the image tag as text and just add the url you want.

Comment: not possible like that, img is thumbnail generated from woocommerce loop

Comment: You can definitely do it inside the loop. Within it instead of calling a function to return the image tag, make your own image tag and just call for the image URL.

Comment: can you send me a example as it makes no sense ... how do you replace the img tag ?

Comment: i figured it out in content-product.php you comment out //do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ); and you replace with <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="My Image Placeholder" />'; ?>